Infer more specific type from dictionary? How to help TypeScript to infer the type?
I got this super code:
export type Locale = "en" | "fr";
export type Namespace = "products" | "home";

const dict = {
  en: {
    home: { title: "My Super Title" },
    products: { product: "Product" },
  },
  fr: {
    home: { title: "Mon Super Titre" },
    products: { product: "Produit" },
  },
};

export const getTranslation = (namespace: Namespace, locale: Locale) => {
  return dict[locale][namespace];
};

const t = await getTranslation("home", "en");
// Typescript infer of T 
// const t: {
//   title: string;
// } | {
//   product: string;
// } | {
//   title: string;
// } | {
//   product: string;
// }


I tought TypeScript would be able to infer correctly this, but it does not.
So my first question, why TypeScript is not able to infer this correctly?
Also can I help it by adding manual typing to getTranslation so it can infer it correctly?
I was expecting:
{
    title: string;
}

By the way, I am using TypeScript "^5"
Maybe I am just not using the right keyword to find the solution.
But I am 100% sure it is possible to having type to fix my issue.

You can simply use generic type parameters.
Instead of typing directly your function parameters as unions (Namespace and Locale), let TS infer a more specific type, while still constraining it to avoid unwanted types:
export const getTranslation = <N extends Namespace, L extends Locale>(namespace: N, locale: L) => {
    return dict[locale][namespace];
};

const t = getTranslation("home", "en");
//    ^? { title: string; }

const t2 = getTranslation("products", "fr");
//    ^? { product: string; }

const t3 = getTranslation("unknown", "other"); // Error as expected: Argument of type '"unknown"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Namespace'.
//                        ~~~~~~~~~

Playground Link
